# incorrect datetime value "2019-06%" - Query works, but with warning

Tags: mysql

```
WHERE theDate LIKE '2019-06%'
```

Is there any "correct" way of running a query like this, or do I have to split up the string first? And in that case, what is the correct way of doing the query if I have the year and month as separate strings. I read that using MONTH and YEAR is not optimal?

Comment: What is the data type of `theDate`?

Comment: Are you looking for a highly optimal solution or one that is decently optimal?

Comment: Data type is DATETIME
In this case it doesn't need to be optimal at all - but a little curious about the optimal way also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest query when you have set indexes properly (faster than LIKE, faster then MONTH, YEAR) will be

```
WHERE thedate BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30'.
```

I'm not sure if the borders are included or excluded, maybe the borders will be last may and/or first july.

Comment: between uses `>=` and `<=` Also make sure `thedate` is indexed

Comment: But this require some lines of code to parse the date string and know how many days the month has etc...

Comment: @JamesT: sure, for example `$date = '2019-07';
$monthStart = $date . '-01';
$monthEnd = $date . '-' . date('t', strtotime($monthStart));`, where `$date` you know (you pass this variable into your query). There are more ways how to find both dates, this is one of them.